# Equation number displaying problem

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

I used `\eqref` to reference two different equations (`\eqref{eq1}` and `\eqref{eq2}`) but it displays the same strange shape as shown below in the image. The equation numbers are 1 & 2, any help?

[image: error]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem in your future posts. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define the label *within* the `equation` (or `align`) environment, not outside:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{equation} f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \end{equation}
\label{eqn:first}
See~\eqref{eqn:first} and~\eqref{eqn:second}.
\begin{equation} f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \label{eqn:second} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically only the second label is within the environment in this case ;-)

Comment: @Mythio: That's true. The example is meant to showcase the difference by both duplicating the OP's output (even though he did not provide some example code/MWE) as well as showing the intended usage.